# jquery conflict in bootstrap between responsive menu and light box image gallery

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I am facing a jQuery conflict in bootstrap between a responsive menu and a lightbox image gallery. When I disable the lightbox, the responsive menu will work. Can anyone help me in resolving it?

Comment: You may use two different version of JQuery Library file. Check it. Else use  JQuery Conflict technique to solve it.  REF: https://api.jquery.com/jquery.noconflict/

Comment: light box is using different version of j query and  responsive menu is using default bootstrap j query file

Comment: Try the below answer.

Answer (score 0):

Call Light Box Jquery inside the below script. **Use "jQuery" instead of "$" symbol**

```
    <script>
 jQuery.noConflict();

    jQuery(document).ready(function(){

  // Call Light Box Jquery here.

 });     
</script>
```

Comment: If I add bootstrap j query file , menu is working. But image slideshow is not working. I'm adding light box j query files at the starting of the page.

Comment: Remove this script . written in 2 times , remove both.

<script src="index_files/vlb_engine/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="index_files/vlb_engine/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script> . one library file enough.(<script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
)

Answer (score 0):

Try bootbox http://bootboxjs.com/ , Its not image galley but you can add HTML(Custom HTML Contents from http://bootboxjs.com/examples.html)